# Assembly.FullName vs. Assembly.ManifestModule.Name

Tags: reflection, .net-assembly

maybe that's a simple question, but I'm wondering, if the following lines will have the same result every time or if it's possible that there are differences.

```
string assemblyName = anyType.Assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] + ".dll";

string assemblyName = anyType.Assembly.ManifestModule.Name;
```

As the first line is executed 150.000 times on startup of our application, there will be many allocations of string. I want to reduce that by the second line, but I'm not sure if it will be the same in every case.

Comment: It makes no difference, a string is created in both cases.  Storing the result in a variable and re-using it is an obvious improvement.

Comment: Are you sure? Because i did that because of memory analysis with a profiler. The Split function creates at least 2 strings and the additional concat with + another one. My question aims if the first part of Assembly.FullName and Assembly.ManifestModule.Name will be equal in every case. Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you fretting over 150,000 vs 300,000 strings when you have a way to use only one.  If *anyType* can be anything then a `Dictionary<Type, string>` would be efficient, at a cost of having your program use more memory.  Which is best is unguessable, you use a profiler to tell you that.

Comment: that specific line is called many times for different types. Partially you're right with the dictionary, maybe some strings would have multiple instances. But that's not the point of the question